# Filter results by user role

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a query that returns the total number of users per a specific meta value (gender), considering only users that are not blocked (user_blocked_access):

```
SELECT umc.meta_value AS label, COUNT(umb.user_id) AS total
FROM wp_users u
INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umc
    ON umc.user_id = u.ID 
    AND umc.meta_key = 'user_gender' 
    AND umc.meta_value <> ''
INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umb
    ON umb.user_id = u.ID 
    AND umb.meta_key = 'user_blocked_access' 
    AND CAST(umb.meta_value AS BINARY) <> '1' 
GROUP BY umc.meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC
```

I have to return only the results for a specific user role:

```
umb.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND umb.meta_value LIKE '%craftsman%'
```

But don't know where I should adds this part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT umc.meta_value AS label, COUNT(umb.user_id) AS total
FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umc
    ON umc.user_id = u.ID  AND
       umc.meta_key = 'user_gender' AND
       umc.meta_value <> '' INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umb
    ON umb.user_id = u.ID AND
       umb.meta_key = 'user_blocked_access' AND 
       CAST(umb.meta_value AS BINARY) <> '1' INNER JOIN 
    wp_usermeta umr
    ON umr.user_id = u.ID AND
       umr.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND
       umr.meta_value LIKE '%craftsman%'
GROUP BY umc.meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Note:  This assumes that there is only one `wp_capabilities` per user.  If there are multiples, then `EXISTS` is safer:

```
SELECT umc.meta_value AS label, COUNT(umb.user_id) AS total
FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umc
    ON umc.user_id = u.ID  AND
       umc.meta_key = 'user_gender' AND
       umc.meta_value <> '' INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta umb
    ON umb.user_id = u.ID AND
       umb.meta_key = 'user_blocked_access' AND
       CAST(umb.meta_value AS BINARY) <> '1'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM wp_usermeta umr
              WHERE umr.user_id = u.ID AND
                    umr.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND
                    umr.meta_value LIKE '%craftsman%'
             )
GROUP BY umc.meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC;
```